# Destination Folder Access Denied - You need permission to perform this action

Tags: windows

Sometimes I get this error message when trying to move, rename, or otherwise manipulate some files or folders on my computer...

[Destination Folder Access Denied You need permission to perform this action http://img222.imageshack.us/img222/1581/destinationfolderaccessms9.jpg](http://img222.imageshack.us/img222/1581/destinationfolderaccessms9.jpg)

What do I need to do to gain control?

Answer (score 10):

don't listen to vista, it tells lies!!!

I had this problem, and could not resolve it by running as admin, taking ownership (I was already owner) etc. turned out the problem was that another process (textpad) had a file open deep underneath the directory I was trying to rename. the error message was completely misleading, the problem was a file open for write, nothing to do with security permissions.

AAaaarghhhh!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Take *ownership* of the folders and files...

1. Right-click the folder that you want to take ownership of, and then click Properties.
2. Click the Security tab, click Advanced, and then click the Owner tab.
3. Click Edit. If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
4. Click the name of the person you want to give ownership to.
5. If you want that person to be the owner of files and subfolders in this folder, select the Replace owner on subcontainers and objects check box.
6. Click OK.

Comment: Took over the ownership, the error stays.

Answer (score 2):

use [unlocker](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/Unlocker.shtml) to know who locked it.

Comment: Used, no locks found.

Answer (score 0):

You may get this error when one of the files contained within the folder may in in use by a running program.

Comment: In my case, it isn't in use.